# Connection to database stuck in asynctask

Tags: java, android, sql

i have a  code which connects to sql server, it works just fine when running it on main thread, but because thread freezes while connecting  i decided to put the code in asyncs task. now it's stuck on connection.getConnection(connectionURL).. ANyone knows why?

```
public class ConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.establishing_cnxtn));
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.connecting));
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        connection = DatabaseHandler.getConnection(MainActivity.this);
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (connection == null)
            Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.could_not_connect, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        else {
            try {
                updateUI();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is database code but I know that the problem is not with this code...

```
 static Connection getConnection(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("ip",MODE_PRIVATE);
    //ip = sharedPreferences.getString("ip","");

    ip = "PC-HASSANSHOUMA"; //database ip
    db = "***"; //database name
    un = "***"; //username to connect to db
    pass = "***"; //password to connect to db
    connectionURL = null;
    port = "1433";

    Log.i("jsbnkjnbsjkdjk","dfdfdfdfdfd");

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Log.i("bjhbdjs","dfdfdfdfdfd");
    if(connection == null)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Log.i("nbkjnjk","dfdfdfdfdfd");
            connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+"192.168.0.112"+"/"+db+";instance=SQL2014;user="+un+";"+"password="+pass+";";
            Log.i("kjhknklnkl","dfdfdfdfdfd");
            connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            Log.i("njknjknj","dfdfdfdfdfd");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            Log.i("klklllk","dfdfdfdfdfd");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            Log.i("nklnkl54564","dfdfdfdfdfd");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    return connection;

}
```

Comment: when creating a connection do you have mainActivity or any activity or any context? If your asyncTask class is inside of your activity or is out of the activity?

Comment: the asyncs task class is inside the mainActivity and the database class is a normal class not inner..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String SERVICE_URL = params[0]  ;
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                String result = downloadUrl(SERVICE_URL,params[1],params[2]); 
                z= result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                z = "error";
                onPostExecute(z);
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
```

and in downloadUrl method of async:this is a custom method

```
private String downloadUrl(String urlString,String iOutputFile,String iOutputPath) throws IOException {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        int len = 1000000; //Is not used
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);  // milliseconds
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);  // milliseconds
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();

            long lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();
            inStream = conn.getInputStream();
            return saveIt(inStream,iOutputFile,iOutputPath,lenghtOfFile);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            return e.getMessage();
        }
        finally {
            if (inStream != null) {
                inStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

saveit is also a custom method for after doing tasks...saveit is a private method of the async class(for processing after downloading ...).
In this sample I got a file from a server and then saving it in phone.

In calling instance of asynctask :

```
new GetGedFileFromServer().execute(file_url4Download,file_Name4Save,file_Path4Save);
```

The name of my asyncTask was GetGedFileFromServer()

Only you must do is creating a string presents file_url4Download ... and finally this is only a sample code you would want to send a file or get a data from a sql server allocated on a server or ... . You could customize the pre and post methods for handling of dialogs ...

Comment: This is not actually my problem, my my problem is when trying to connecy to to database it freezes on DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL)

Comment: what is meaning of freez ? It means no responding?

Comment: everything now work thank your for your try to help.. the same code suddenly works